# Autofilter in Loop runs slowly first time, then rapidly?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

**Things to know**:

- Crosspost from here:
  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/843474-visual-basic-applications-why-does-autofilter-loop-run-slowly-first-time-then-rapidly-after.html
- Excel 2010
- 2nd text file being filtered is similar to the first - both use every
  row except one in the Excel sheet and cover 33 columns. (The third
  one is much smaller and I am not surprised to see it take a shorter
  time)
- I have the complete macro available if needed, but the posting
  guidelines said to try to avoid posting unnecessary code

**What I am trying to accomplish**:

- Understand and resolve why the below code section, which autofilters,
  takes 25 minutes to run on first loop, but takes much less time (10
  seconds) on what should be a similar second loop and when done
  manually (also about 10 seconds)

**What I've done so far**:

- Used timers to observe how long the code section takes to execute on
  each iteration of the loop.

  - First iteration takes 25 minutes
  - Second iteration takes 10 seconds
  - Third iteration takes 0 seconds (not surprising, see above)

Thank you so much for your help, and please let me know if I can provide more helpful information. I tried to be as concise but informative as possible.

```
Double1 = Now 'Delete Me        'Filter and delete dates before cutoff
Long1 = Application.CountA(.Columns(8))
Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(Long1, 8))
With Range1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & DateSerial(2012, 10, 1)  'DateSerial uses (Year, Month, Day)
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
Double2 = Now 'Delete Me
```

Comment: if you autofilter on dates it would be beneficial to sort on dates before autofilter. Deleting rows can take some time. Does the file contain any arrayformulae, conditional formatting, named ranges that have to be calculated over and over again ? How many rows are you talking about ?

Comment: Agreed, mole and I were talking about that at mrexcel and I have been implementing it. --- No, but I always turn off automatic calculation and screenupdating in my macros. --- I did not know how to express it better, but what I was trying to say above is that both the first and second file being parsed by the loop use every single Excel row. That is, 1048576 rows once I've added the header.

Comment: @pnuts one run for each of three files, good question

Comment: Good question, going to test that now!

Answer (score 0):

Using ADO instead of autofilter should give you more consistent times as long as you don't mind copying the results to a new sheet.

Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" then try this code (substituting in the appropriate worksheet and column names; remember to keep the $ sign after the sheet name in the SELECT statement):

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [DateToCheck] >= #10/01/2012#", cn

Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close
```